# CSS tree view with lines connecting nodes

Tags: html, css, tree

Is this possible to create a tree component using only HTML and CSS that contains lines connecting nodes? I'm trying to avoid nested nodes containing text with CSS styles

See the [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjOCX.png) as an example. It heavily inspired by [Autodesk Maya inspector tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7pw9.jpg)

I achieved the following but I don't like it because the lines are not connected:

https://codepen.io/xotonic/pen/JRLAOR

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li class="container"><p><r>Testing</r> </p>
    <ul>
        <li><p><r>Testing 1</r></p></li>
        <li><p><r>Testing 2</r></p></li>
        <li class="container"><p><r>Testing</r> </p>
            <ul>
                <li><p><r>Testing 1</r></p></li>
                <li><p><r>Testing 2</r></p></li>
                <li><p><r>Testing 3</r></p></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="container"><p><r>Testing</r> </p>
    <ul>
        <li><p><r>Testing 1</r></p></li>
        <li><p><r>Testing 2</r></p></li>
        <li><p><r>Testing 3</r></p></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="container"><p><r>Testing </r></p>
    <ul>
        <li class="empty"><p><r>empty</r></p></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { padding-left: 1em; }
li { padding-left: 1em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px; 
}
li.container { border-bottom: 0px; 
}
li.empty { font-style: italic;
  color: silver;
  border-color: silver;
}
p { margin: 0;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em; 
  
}
p:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
r {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
ul { 
  border-top: 1px dotted black; 
  margin-left: -1em;     
  padding-left: 2em; 
}
ul li:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -17px;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Have you tried something to achieve this?

Comment: @Xufox I try to add `:before` pseudo-element to draw circle in content div, but lines drawing to the div instead circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made my own implementation. There are more additional elements.

https://github.com/xotonic/flex-tree

Comment: what a pity, you are using divs instead of uls in your github code, though a nested structure would be semantically correct (as in your question's code).

Answer (score 7):

*Dylancwood* provides CSS for a nested structure as in the question's example (`ul` in `ul` instead of `div` in `div` as in the answer).

See https://gist.github.com/dylancwood/7368914

To stay with nesting is semantically correct (and still looks correct without any CSS at all)! (Manuel Matuzović wrote a really good article on [ol vs. ul .vs div](https://www.htmhell.dev/tips/ol-vs-ul-vs-div/).)

Anyways, *Dylancwood* uses light-weight `border-left` in combination with `:before` for drawing the vertical and horizontal connecting lines. A working fiddle is linked in his gist.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this solution seems right: [Draw a Tree Structure With Only CSS](https://two-wrongs.com/draw-a-tree-structure-with-only-css.html)

- Defines :before and :after for each list item
- Use position absolute and negative left to position them both to the left of the list item
- Use one to draw the vertical line and the other to draw the horizontal line

  - Lines are defined as a border-left or border-top with a top value to move the line down
  - The height and top of the vertical line can also be customized, depending on whether a list item is a last sibling